# ng2-toastr shows only after I refresh the page and submit the form again just for one condition

Tags: angular

I am facing a very strange issue in case of ng2 toastr. for one condition, it only shows when I refresh the page and for all other condition it is showing neatly. As an alternative, only for this case I am using angular material snackbar but it is not looking very consistent. this is my code snippet.

```
   this.dataService.postPickupData(this.dataForServer).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.responseData = data;
          console.log(this.responseData);
          // if (this.responseData) {
          console.log(this.responseData.status.responseCode);
          if (this.responseData.status.responseCode === 50005) {
            console.log(this.toastr)
           this.toastr.error("Slots not available!", "Oops!");
            console.log('no slots available');
            this.noSlots = 'No Slots Available';
            this.load = false;
           var message ='Slots Not Available ';
        //    alert("checking if slots are available");
            this.toastr.error('Slots not available!', 'Oops!');
             this.snackBar.open(message, "OK");
          this.snackBar.open(message, "OK", {
           duration: 2000,
         verticalPosition: 'top'
             });
          } else if (
            this.responseData.status.responseMessage === 'Success'
          ) {
            this.toastr.success('Return Scheduled!', 'Confirmed!');
            this.router.navigate(['scheduled']);
          }
          // } else {
          //   this.toastr.error("Server is unreachable!", "Network Error!");
          // }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error');
        }
      );
```

If I refresh the page, it will work and for all other condition it does not even need refreshment.

Comment: Which one of the calls is not opening correctly? And where in your code are you trying to open it? Inside an http call? So the surrounding function and where it is called might be helpful here

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt , in my code snippet, here,   this.toastr.error('Slots not available!', 'Oops!');

Comment: You have it twice in there, are both not opening correctly? And is the rest of the code execute, can you see the console logs?

Comment: I have seen. condition is fine, it is coming inside. 2 times I put, as I thought may be it I put a slightly above, then may be it works. after refreshing, it will show two times.